# SessionStorage en Javascript al enviar datos es NULL

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Buenas e estado investigando pero no e encontrado como hacer que "SessionStorage" al pasar los datos no me retorne un valor NULL
Codigo-1:

```
function TravelDAta(){
    let txtNombre = document.getElementById("txtNombreCompleto");
    let txtID = document.getElementById("txtID");
    let txtPhone = document.getElementById("txtTelp");
    let txtEmail = document.getElementById("txtMail");
    let txtCountry = document.getElementById("countries");
    let txtTypeCoins = document.getElementById("coin");
    let txtTypePay = document.getElementById("paid");
    let txtMonto = document.getElementById("Topay");
    let txtServiceTime = document.getElementById("service1");
    let txtBank = document.getElementById("txtbanks");
    let txtNewServ = document.getElementById("txtBegin");
    let content = [txtNombre,txtID,txtPhone,txtEmail,txtCountry,txtMonto,txtTypeCoins,txtTypePay,txtServiceTime,txtBank,txtNewServ];
    sessionStorage.content = JSON.stringify(content);
}
```

Codigo-2:

```
let arrive = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.content | "[]")
    let register = [];
    register.push.apply(arrive);
    document.getElementById('txtNewNom').placeholder=register[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los métodos para obtener y establecer objetos en el sessionStorage son:

setItem() permite establecer objetos:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('llave', 'valor');
```

getItem() permite acceder a objetos:

```
const data = sessionStorage.getItem('llave');
```